# Error in Javascript return

Tags: javascript, function, return

I want to receive HTML code in `chat.openChat()` from `chat.getHtmlPage()` but return operation is "undefined".

```
var chat = {
    openChat : function($url){
        $('#popup').html(chat.getHtmlPage($url)); // It's wrong, UNDEFINED.
    },

    getHtmlPage : function($url){
        $.ajax({
            url: $url
        }).done(function($html) { 
            return $html; // It's OK! $html is with correct html, see with alert().
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnChat').click(function(){
        chat.openChat($(this).attr('href')); // It's OK!
        ...
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. You have to wait for it te request to complete to get its return value. As it is, your callback doesn't even return from the containing function: it merely returns from the callback, doing nothing. You should let your custom AJAX function take a callback of its own to call once it has the necessary data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default AJAX request is asynchronous, so it ends after you get result from `getHtmlPage`. Even if you change it to be synchronous, you will still have undefined in `openChat`, because you return value from `done` handler, not from `getHtmlPage`.

You should provide a callback to `getHtmlPage` method. Example:

```
var chat = {
    openChat : function($url){
        chat.getHtmlPage($url, function(html) {
            $('#popup').html(html); 
        });
    },
    getHtmlPage : function($url, callback){
        $.ajax({
            url: $url
        }).done(callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. I like this. Thank you.

Comment: This is probably the most clean way indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax calls are asynchronously, that's why you can't use the return of the ajax function immediately. to store the result in $('popup').

You will have to do something like this:

```
openChat : function($url){

    chat.getHtmlPage($url));
},

setHtmlPage : function ($html) {
    $('popup').html($html);
},


getHtmlPage : function($url){

    $.ajax({
        url: $url
    }).done(function($html) { 
        chat.setHtmlPage($html);
    });
}
```

You may also want to have a look to the jquery documentation about ajax. There is a way to make ajax requests synchronously, but that will block your browser and it's deprecated in the newer versions. (and it's not really ajax after all)

[Check the part about async](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
var chat = {
    openChat : function($url){
        chat.getHtmlPage($url);
    },

    getHtmlPage : function($url){
        $.ajax({
            url: $url
        }).done(function($html) { 
            $('#popup').html($html); 
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnChat').click(function(){
        chat.openChat($(this).attr('href')); // It's OK!
        ...
        return false;
    });
});
```

AJAX is asynchronouse. Once you call it, script exection goes to next line and `.done` is called later, after request is finished. Also, return from done will do nothing. As it's jquery ajax event triggered after request is done. And jquery will not pass returned value to upper level of code even if you will make it work in synchronouse way.

Comment: Yes, this two solution (same really) i want. But i want construct one GENERAL function, but this is impossible with async... Pain for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first 'A' in AJAX is 'Asynchronous', this means: by the time the .done() gets called, the rest of your code already moved on. With this knowledge, a `return` in .done() simply makes no sense.
Instead, we just deactiveate the asynchronous behaviour of AJAX, setting `async: false` in the .ajax-object. But be aware that this is not the original purpose of AJAX and it may cause trouble in some browsers.

Oone solution would then be to set the `return` into your `getHtmlPage` (in addtion to setting async to false!):

```
getHtmlPage : function($url){

    //a new variable to store the ajax-result
    //defining it here, so it's only visible within the scope of getHtmlPage
    var html;

    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        async: false
    }).done(function($html) {
        //we use the html variable here to store the result 
        html = $html;
    });

    //finally returning the variable
    return html;
}
```

This way, your return statement won't be executed until the ajax-call finishes.

Comment: As far as I know it will still be returned (nulL) before the ajax is ready in this way.

Comment: As far as i know it will wait for the ajax call to finish, as I make it synchronous with `async: false` - will test it when I get the time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

To do one general function (original idea).

```
var chat = {

    openChat : function($url, $htmlElement){

        chat.setHtmlPage($url, $htmlElement);
    },


    setHtmlPage : function($url, $htmlElement){

        $.ajax({
            url: $url
        }).done(function($html) { 
            $($htmlElement).html($html);
        });
    }

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btnChat').click(function(){

        chat.openChat($(this).attr('href'), '#popup');

        ...

        return false;
    });

});
```